# How to generate SVG dataURL with p5.js and p5.js-svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, p5.js

I am trying to generate an image using p5.js and p5.js-svg and then save the SVG xml as a dataURL for storage. Here is an example script that I've simplified for this question:

```
const canvasWidth = 600;
const canvasHeight = 600;
const bgColor = "#fffcf3";

let unencodedDataURL = "";

const sketch = (p) => {
  p.setup = () => {
    p.createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, p.SVG);
    p.background(bgColor);
    p.noLoop();
  }

  p.draw = () => {
    p.noFill();

    p.ellipse(z
      canvasWidth / 2,
      canvasHeight / 2,
      150,
      150
    );
    unencodedDataURL = p.getDataURL();
    console.log(`inside: ${unencodedDataURL}`);
  }
}

const test = new p5(sketch, document.body);
console.log(`outside: ${unencodedDataURL}`);
```

The first log statement prints the right dataURL. But of course the second log statement executes before the one inside `draw()` and I cannot figure out how to capture the dataURL correctly. I'm sure I am missing something in the p5.js or p5.js-svg libraries and there is an easier way.  But I am stuck. Anyone have an idea here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because p5js run asynchronous,
You can add callback or write a Promise to get data after sketch draw, like this

```js
var handleDataCallback = null;

//........
p.ellipse(
    canvasWidth / 2,
    canvasHeight / 2,
    150,
    150
);
unencodedDataURL = p.getDataURL();
if (handleDataCallback) handleDataCallback(unencodedDataURL);
//....

//for callback
handleDataCallback = dataURL => {
//todo something with dataURL
}
```

if you want to write as a function to generate image

```js
function generateImage(param, callback) {
    return new Promise(resolve  => {

        //......
        // do something
        p.ellipse(
            canvasWidth / 2,
            canvasHeight / 2,
            150,
            150
        );
       var unencodedDataURL = p.getDataURL();
        if (callback) callback(unencodedDataURL);
        resolve(unencodedDataURL);
        //  ....


    })


}

//use Promise
generateImage(yourParam, null).then(unencodedDataURL=>{
    console.log(`outside: ${unencodedDataURL}`);
})
//or callback
generateImage(yourParam, unencodedDataURL=> {
    console.log(`outside: ${unencodedDataURL}`);
});
```